# Leaflet error: Invalid LatLng object: ( , undefined)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to move my L.polygon data to a different file. I'm using jQuery to get the data from the separate file. It seems like it should be returning the exact same data I was using when I had it as a L.polygon in the index.html file, but instead it's returning this error:

```
Invalid LatLng object: ( , undefined)
```

I searched for the error, but it seems that everyone else who has reported it was using a different data type than I am.

Here's the full example:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <style type="text/css">
  #map {
    height: 500px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = L.map('map').setView([33.720818, -84.240], 11);

  $.get("data/temp.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var temp = new L.polygon(data).setStyle(defaultStyle).addTo(map);
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

data/temp.csv:

```
[
[33.829205,-84.377261],
[33.829121,-84.377257],
[33.829039,-84.377271],
[33.828937,-84.377204],
[33.828871,-84.377122]
]
```

Edit: To clarify, adding the following to the index.html file works just fine, but bringing it in from another file (above) isn't working.

```
var temp = L.polygon([
  [33.829205,-84.377261],
  [33.829121,-84.377257],
  [33.829039,-84.377271],
  [33.828937,-84.377204],
  [33.828871,-84.377122]
  ]).setStyle(defaultStyle).addTo(map);
```

Comment: `data` here is might be a string, meaning that you're doing `L.polygon("[...]")` instead of `L.polygon([...])`. Maybe try `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`, or do `data = $.parseJSON(data);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`L.polygon()` expects an array of `LatLng` objects.

You need to either iterate over the array, creating a `LatLng` out of each of those elements, or wrap this list in a GeoJSON object and use the GeoJSON class to do that for you.

Something like:

```
L.geoJson({"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": data}).setStyle(defaultStyle).addTo(map);
```

**edit from comments**: It turns out that `L.polygon()` does actually convert an array of arrays to an array of `LatLng` automatically. The problem was instead that you need to be explicit and pass in "json" as the last argument to `$.get()` in order to ensure that it's actually parsing the string as JSON, rather than returning the raw string.

Comment: In that case, why does this work fine? 

    var temp = L.polygon([
 [33.829205,-84.377261],
 [33.829121,-84.377257],
 [33.829039,-84.377271],
 [33.828937,-84.377204],
 [33.828871,-84.377122]
    ]).setStyle(defaultStyle).addTo(map);

Comment: Oh, hm, maybe it does automatically convert an array of arrays. In that case, are you sure that `$.get()` is parsing as JSON rather than returning you the string? You should be explicit and pass in `"json"` as the last argument to `$.get()` in order to ensure that it's actually parsing the string.

Comment: This and @apsillers answers both work. Any thoughts about whether it's preferable to iterate over the array, convert to GeoJSON, or change the $.get() command?

Comment: @user2926101 Just changing the `$.get()` command should be sufficient; there's no reason to make it more complicated than that, as long as that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.parse(data)` .for me,it works.